# Self-disappearing String as Notification on Status-bar in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to create a notification on Status bar in Android which shows up a String and disappear without user intervention after a specified period of time.

I don't want the notification to launch any other activity or service.

I am trying to use NotificationCompat without `setContentIntent()` and my application is crashing with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: contentIntent required`

**My Question**
How to create a self-disappearing String Notification in Android which does not launch another activity or service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu need to `cancel()` it yourself. The simplest way would be to use AlarmManager, set up alarm once you show the notification to occur `now+offset` and then cancel your notification.

Comment: Even thought this is the way to go, it would still get the same error, since the content intent is needed for the notification to be created. @coding crow, just create an empty intent and remove with the cancel() method